# Migrating Multisite Setup to Localhost Running Nginx 404 for /files

Tags: migrations, multi-sites

I'm migrating a Drupal 7 based site to localhost. The site is currently setup in a multi-site configuration in the following way:

```
    webroot
    -drupal
    --sites
    ---example.com
    ----files
    ----settings.php
    ----sites.php
    ----modules
    ----themes 
    ----libraries
    ----private
```

On my local dev server I imported the Db and set up the site in the following configuration:

```
 webroot
 -sites
 --example.com
 ---files
 ---settings.php
 ---sites.php
 ---modules
 ---themes 
 ---libraries
 ---private
```

While I'm able to see the pages and login to the site, everything in my /files folder is returning a 404. All of the aggregated js files and images are broken and when I try to access any site admin links, I get an error.

I've check the permissions for the /files folder and files and everything seems fine. I've tried various suggestions like checking the .htaccess file, and adding $base_url in settings, and even turning off clean urls, but nothing seems to work. I even tried to set permissions on the folder and files to 777, but no luck.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out. I'm using VVV Varying Vagrant Vagrants for my local development environment, https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV

Needed to customize the nginx configuration files for my site to accommodate a Drupal installation. The issue with the /files folder contents being 404 was largely due to this. After I configured nginx correctly for Drupal it worked like a charm.

You can find a sample config file here for Drupal: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/